# How can I resize the cells in a collection view dependent on the device screen size?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, size, collectionview

I'm working in Swift and I want my cells to look similar to how it does on this picture on an iPhone 8 plus 
[image]

But when I load it on a iPad, the size of the cells do not adjust to the screen size. It looks like this: [image]

Does anyone know how I can do this in my CollectionViewController?

Comment: please show your tried code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a delegate Method in UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


    let collectionViewCellSize = collectionView.frame.size.width / 10 // to show 10 cells in a row

    return CGSize(width: collectionViewCellSize, height: collectionViewCellSize)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Any time Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let yourWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width) / 10.0
    let yourHeight = yourWidth

    return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: @Tessa, if this helps you than you can accept this answer as well as upvote this.